# How do I set up a build for the GridWorld case study in Sublime text 2?

Tags: build, classpath, sublimetext2, gridworld

I am new to Sublime text 2 and don't know how to set up the build files. I've been trying to run the GridWorld case study, but I don't know how to setup the classpath to the GridWorld.jar file. This is the build I currently have:

```
    {
     "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","&&","java", "$file_base_name"],
     "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
     "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17\\bin\\",
     "selector": "source.java",
     "shell": true
    }
```

I've tried creating a CLASSPATH variable in my system environment variables, but when I try to run my BugRunner code I get an Error: Could not find or load main class BugRunner. If there is any other info you need I'll add more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add `-cp .` to `java` command

```
{
 "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name","-cp",".","&&","java", "$file_base_name","-cp","."],
 "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
 "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_17\\bin\\",
 "selector": "source.java",
 "shell": true
}
```